# Is there a latus other than the one in the rectum?

Tags: terminology, conic-sections

[image]
The name "Latus Rectum" sounds so very specific.
Infact when I once asked why it is called as such, an explanation stated that the concave side of a parabola is called a rectum and that latus was just gibberish for a line segment.

Is there a latus somewhere else in geometry other than the latus rectum or did someone just shove that name in for laughs?
No, seriously, [high schoolers seem to always remember it](http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/a8/a87504325709e5268a39d7fd52ccccc429aa673e0f63cbd022de32e647b79fc7.jpg) even if they don't know what a parabola is.

Comment: Latus is Latin for "wide" or "broad." Rectum here means to make straight (a line.) Since "latus" is the an adjective, it's wrong to ask if there is "a latus."

Comment: No, "latus" here is a noun (third declension neuter) meaning "side" and "rectum" is an adjective meaning "straight".

Comment: If "rectum" was a noun it would be neuter, and then the adjective form would be "latum".  Also the adjective generally follows the noun.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: So, I should have asked if there was a rectum other than the one in the latus?

Comment: "the latus" is still wrong. @Nick

Comment: @Thomas: *The latus* is wrong only because we don’t use the Latin noun *latus* 'side, flank' in English; it is a noun here, quite distinct from the adjective *lātus* 'wide', and *the latus* is parallel to *the Tintenfass*, for example. The real error in the title is *the rectum*, since *rectum* is an adjective.

Comment: @Nick: Thomas is simply wrong, and Robert Israel is correct. What you should have asked is whether there was a *latus* other than the *latus rectum*, literally a *side* other than the *straight side*.

Comment: Though I have to say that the title is eye-catching!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *rect-* in *rectum* is [related](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language) with the English *right* or *(st)raight*, as well as the neologism *correct*. And *latus* means side, but also wide, or width. The expression simply means *straight side*. Which is also why it's probably left untranslated, since (at least word-wise) it's synonymous with the notion of *straight line*, which however bears different connotations. (In Romanian, for instance, *lat* means broad, and *latura* means side, while *drept* means straight or direct).

Answer (score 4):

Latus is Latin for "side".  In anatomy it is the flank of the body.  I'm not aware of any use of "latus" in mathematics other than "latus rectum", but "lateral" is derived from it, and thus "quadrilateral" etc.